# No Data Available issue in HiveQL

Tags: hive

I am trying a simple JOIN of 2 table using Hive(0.14) and i get "No Data Avaialble". Both tables have more than 100 Millions records.

The code is very simple as shown below:

```
CREATE VIEW mem_info_1 AS
SELECT mbr.MBR_KEY,mbr.BRTH_DT,mbr.GNDR_CD,a.cms_cntrct_nbr
FROM MBR_MEDCR_CVRG a
JOIN MBR mbr ON (a.MBR_KEY = mbr.MBR_KEY);
```

Please advise what could be wrong

Comment: Is select query running fine ?

Comment: Yes ...just now while debugging i removed the CREATE VIEW mem_info_1 AS .......just ran the select clause and it is running....so there is something funny about CREATE View clause .....